# How to properly save values into an array when using for loop

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to push `cumDistance` into `cumDistances` array for every iteration of the for loop but I am having trouble.

```
var inTrade = false
var entry = 0.
var exit = 0.
distance = 0.

entryCon = ta.crossover(ta.rsi(close, 10), 20) and not inTrade
exitCon = ta.crossunder(ta.rsi(close, 10), 80) and inTrade

cumDistances = array.new_float()
for i=1 to 5
    if entryCon[1]
        entry := close[1]
        inTrade := true

    if exitCon[1]
        exit := close[1]
        inTrade := false
        distance := exit - entry*i

    cumDistance = ta.cum(distance)
    array.push(cumDistances, cumDistance)
```

The values inside the `cumDistances` array that I get are all the same:

1. -43.41588
2. -43.41588
3. -43.41588
4. -43.41588
5. -43.41588

.

```
if entryCon[1]
    entry := close[1]
    inTrade := true

if exitCon[1]
    exit := close[1]
    inTrade := false
    distance := exit - entry*i //changed i to 1,2,3,4,5

cumDistance = ta.cum(distance)
```

If I run the code without for loops(like the code just above), these are the values of `cumDistance` I get for their respective iteration.

1. 0.02016
2. -10.83885
3. -21.69786
4. -32.55687
5. -43.41588

It seems that the array `cumDistances` only saves the value of `cumDistance`  for the last iteration of the for loop to all index of the array.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**
Response to elod008:

```
cumDistances = array.new_float()
for i=1 to 5
    var distances = array.new_float()
    if entryCon[1]
        entry := close[1]
        inTrade := true

    if exitCon[1]
        exit := close[1]
        inTrade := false
        distance := exit - entry*i
        array.push(distances, distance)


    cumDistance = array.sum(distances)
    array.push(cumDistances, cumDistance)
    //array.clear(distances) <---- placing this here, I will get NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,Nan as result

plot(array.size(cumDistances), "no. of index", display=display.data_window)

table1 = table.new(position.top_right, 10, 10)
table.cell(table1, 0, 0, str.tostring(array.get(cumDistances, 0)) + ", "
                         + str.tostring(array.get(cumDistances, 1)) + ", "
                         + str.tostring(array.get(cumDistances, 2)) + ", "
                         + str.tostring(array.get(cumDistances, 3)) + ", "
                         + str.tostring(array.get(cumDistances, 4)))
```

Comment: How exactly did you plot your array results?

Comment: through tables and array.get()

Comment: Are you 100% sure your results are from the bar where exitCon[1] is true?

Comment: Yes at exitCon[1] distance is calculated. ta.cum(distance) just adds up all distances.

Comment: You can run the code without the for loop and check cumDistance. Just change i to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code. There seems to be no error in the calculation. What you're experiencing is that `ta.cum()` works on a series float and sums for you the absolute total as it is supposed to.
However if your conditional that adds new values to the array is false in some iterations, `ta.cum()` receives n times the default 0.0 of `distance`, what does not meet your expectations. Your array gets pushed the series cumDistance altered by the built-in function then.
I would not recommend using `ta.cum()` in this case. I'd rather collect and sum up the relevant results in a `var` variable/object/matrix etc. depending on your needs.

Comment: I made a var distances array and used array.sum() on that array and pushed it inside cumDistances. I still get same answers for the same every index. I edited my post, added the new code.

Comment: It's because you have apparently 5+ bars until your exit condition meets. That was the problem with the 1st ta.cum() version too. If on a bar no exit condition meets, your distances array remains the same resulting in the same "sum" result until you update the array. Use label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(cumDistances)) instead of table. You'll see that if exit condition meets the result will change. But if it does not, you'll get repetative values.

Comment: Thank you! I can get what I need now thanks to you, just need to tweak it a little bit more. Really appreciate the help, almost gave up on this one hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You declare both `entry` and `exit` as `close[1]`, which means that you just do the same calculation five times and push it into array (also five times). I assume you want to cycle over the last 5 bars; in this case, you need to change `close[1]` to `close[i]` so that on each loop iteration, it requests the `close` value farther into the past.

Comment: Im essentially trying to backtest, expecting a different cumulative distance (cumDistance) for every iteration of the for loop. It is my intention for it to do the same calculation five times and push cumDistance into array. Except I am expecting a different values for each iteration since cumDistance = exit - entry*i

Comment: and I'm not trying to cycle over only the last five bars, I'm trying cycle through all bars